# Error: Node Sass version 7.0.3 is incompatible with ^4.0.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sass, node-sass

Установил `node-sass` версии `7.0.3`
Версия `node js - 17.0.9`
Версия `npm -8.5.5`

Пытался ограничиться модулем **sass** вместо **node-sass**, но пишет

```
To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass.
Импортирую как "import styles from 'file.module.scss'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло удаление node_modules и выполнение команды npm install.

Answer (score 0):

**node-sass** устарел, используйте **sass**

```
 npm uninstall node-sass
 npm i -D sass
```

или

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add -D sass
```

Comment: я не фронтенд разработчик, но меня настораживает, что у ТС в вопросе есть строчка: `Пытался ограничиться модулем sass вместо node-sass`. И Вы ему именно это и советуете.